Remote kernel hangs and quietly quits
I have trouble using Mathematica remotely...
My local machine is a Windows using Mathematica 14.0.
The remote machine is a Linux also using Mathematica 14.0.
The connection between both machines is via private/public keys so no password is needed.
If I do "ssh user@machine MathKernel" in a terminal, it works and I have the Mathematica prompt.
In Mathematica on the local machine, I have configured the remote kernel using the basic options.
If I try to execute a cell remotely :

the cell is marked as "executing"
I see in a "top" command on the remote machine that a MathKernel process has launched but then stays at 0% cpu
It hangs like this for 30-40 seconds and then it quits with the message "The remote process for kernel 'kernel name' has unexpectedly terminated with error 2.  Output from stderr:
None"

Any help would be appreciated :)
